# In Numbers, is there a way to get the row instead of the value when using a MAX or MIN Function?

Tags: numbers

In Numbers, is there a way to get the *row* instead of the *value* when using a MAX or MIN Function?

For example, let's take this sheet:

```
bread  10
cheese 20
meat   35
```

What I am trying to do is to show the most expensive food by comparing all price values, getting the *row* number of the MAX value and then print the respective food on that line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `INDEX(MATCH)` this can be easily accomplished.

#### Formulas

This formula returns the food label:
`=INDEX(Foods, MATCH(MIN(Cost),Cost))`
[image: Min formula returning food label]

- The **INDEX** function returns the value in the cell located at the intersection of the specified row and column within a collection of cells or from an array returned by an array function.
- The **MATCH** function returns the position of a value within a collection.

This formula returns the Row number:
`=ROW(INDEX(Foods,MATCH(MIN(Cost),Cost)))`
[image: Row number function]

- The **ROW** function returns the row number of the row containing a specified cell.

Replacing **MIN** with **MAX** returns the row with the Max result.
[image: Formula results]

Further information on these functions can be found in the [**Functions reference.**](https://help.apple.com/functions/mac/7.2/#/ffa59cc33b)

> **ROW**
>
> The ROW function returns the row number of the row containing a
> specified cell.
>
> ROW(cell)
> • cell: An optional cell reference to a single table cell. The
> referenced cell that can contain any value, or be empty. If cell is
> omitted, as in =ROW(), the function returns the row number of the cell
> that contains the formula.
>
> Examples
> =ROW(B7) returns 7, the number of row 7.
>
> =ROW() returns the absolute row number of the cell containing the function